# Can't boot after editing/etc/init.d/rc

Tags: boot, grub2, 14.10

I followed the instructions of a website that told me to change `currency=none` to `currency=shell` in `/etc/init.d/rc` and now my laptop stay in splash screen.

Comment: Try with this command pastebinit /etc/init.d/rc

Comment: How?I can't boot now...

Comment: I fixed it myself(yay!) I went to grub menu, selected recovery mode, made the system writable and used the command sudo nano /etc/init.d/rc

Comment: Glad to know the issue has fixed !

Comment: Just so you know, concurrency=shell is the default on Ubuntu for some versions now, so that advice is worse than useless for speeding up boot. Also, could you post what you did as answer and mark it as accepted to help future visitors?

Comment: @muru Here it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I went to the GRUB menu by quickly press and hold the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key when I see a logo of my computer manufacturer and
- Select the line which starts with "Advanced options", and then the line ending with "(recovery mode)"
- Choose "Drop to root shell prompt".
- Mount the system to read/write by enter the command `mount -o remount,rw /`
- Type `sudo nano /etc/init.d/rc`
- Replace `currency=shell` with `currency=none`
- Type `sudo shutdown -r now` to reboot